# NullpointerException when connection to Postgres from Spark -- why?

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new spark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("mySparkApp")
    val sc = new spark.SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val jdbcUrl = "1.2.34.567" 
    val jdbcUser = "someUser"
    val jdbcPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    val tableName = "myTable"
    val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    Class.forName(driver)

    val df = sqlContext
            .read
            .format("jdbc")
            .option("driver", driver)
            .option("url", jdbcUrl)
            .option("userName", jdbcUser)
            .option("password", jdbcPassword)
            .option("dbtable", tableName) // NullPointerException occurs here
            .load()
  }
}
```

I want to connect to a Postgres database on my LAN from Spark. During runtime, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at <redacted>?.main(App.scala:42)
    at <redacted>.App.main(App.scala)
```

Is there an obvious reason why there's a nullpointer exception at the `option("dbtable", tableName)` line? I'm using spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7 with Scala 2.11.12. For the postgres dependency, I'm using this version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can I see your tableName? It should be all the query: `.option("dbtable", "select * from databaseName.tableName")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message (which isn't very helpful for troubleshooting) is probably not against option `dbtable`, but option `url`.

It looks like your `jdbcUrl` is missing the URL protocol `jdbc:postgresql://` as its prefix.  Here's a link re: [Spark's JDBC data sources](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html).